# Could not connect to development server. fix solution didn't work

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, nodes, npm-install

I tried the fix solution but nothing change, I also check the other solution in the other sites.
see image to see the error. 
[Error Screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j5xh9.png)

Comment: Are you using React Native? [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38290022/react-native-could-not-connect-to-development-server-on-android-device)? Not Xamarin.Android?

Comment: i use react native sir. you view the image to view the error.

Comment: Hi, are you using the emulator or device?

Comment: hello, i use genymotion emulator sir.

Comment: Please refer to [this](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/15388), it is normal, it happened when I learn the RN, I remember that I spend several day to get it work. Just try it. And you should add RN tag, not Xamarin.Android.

Comment: ok sir, thank you very much. and sorry for the tags, i already fix it.

Comment: Happy code, good luck. And one more question, why not use Xamarin? Did you give up?

Comment: ouch.. hahahahahahahaha
apparently, yes sir. because i'm doing this for my thesis project, and i think xamarin is too much hard to learn before this summer ends. i have like 2 months to make at least 50-60% of my project.